# Association not found error after upgrading to Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many, ruby-on-rails-6

After upgrading my app to Rails 6, model which has many to many relationship causes an error saying that 
`Association named 'kulits_efloresensi_kulits' was not found on Kulit; perhaps you misspelled it?`

On Rails 5 it was working fine.
Here are the models:

```
class Kulit < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :efloresensi_kulits
    belongs_to :physical_check, optional: true

class EfloresensiKulit < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :kulits
```

The error occurs on line:

`@physical_checks.reverse.each do |data|`

I found that the join table was named 'efloresensi_kulits_kulits', so I tried to define it in the model

```
class Kulit < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :efloresensi_kulits, join_table: "efloresensi_kulits_kulits"

class EfloresensiKulit < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :kulits, join_table: "efloresensi_kulits_kulits"
```

But the error still occurs. 
How can I fix this error?

**FIXED**

apparently `kulits_efloresensi_kulits` was mentioned in the code, I changed it to correct name and it was fixed. 
But I still wonder why it did not raise an error in Rails 5.

Comment: Which line causes the error? Do you have `kulits_efloresensi_kulits` somewhere in your code? Do you have any more lines in the models?

Comment: Please add more context: the exception trace, what do you do in order to reproduce the error.

Comment: @Vasilisa i checked my code again, indeed i have that `kulits_efloresensi_kulits` in my code. I changed it to `efloresensi_kulits_kulits` then it was fixed. Thank you very much.
But I still wonder why it did not raise an error in Rails 5.

Comment: @AryabhimaA.Rahman happy to help :) We can try to answer 'why it did not raise an error in Rails 5' if you add the corresponding part of code, which contained kulits_efloresensi_kulits